# underscore filter array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have the following array of objects:

`[{key: "test", values: [{key: "2015-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]}, {}], ...]`

I want to filter by the `key` value to only be left with values after a certain date.

I currently have this, but the resulting the structure is wrong

`_.map(temp1, function(value, key) { return _.filter(value.values, function(v) { return v.key > "2015-05"; }); });`

Comment: *"I am using `_.map` and `_.filter` but currently stuck."* If you show us what you've tried (particularly the `_.filter` one), we can help you understand what's wrong with what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement on Frank's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43069842/1084004):

```js
var data = [
  {
    key: "1", 
    values: [
      {key: "2014-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2015-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2013-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]}
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "2", 
    values: [
      {key: "2014-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2015-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2013-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]}
    ]
  }
];

var a = _.map(data, (d) => {
  d.values = _.filter(d.values, (v) => v.key > "2014");
  return d;
});
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

No need to parse this date format, a string comparison will suffice. Important to note, despite the `_.map` operation, this will modify the original.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
var data = [
  {
    key: "1", 
    values: [
      {key: "2014-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2015-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2013-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]}
    ]
  },
  {
    key: "2", 
    values: [
      {key: "2014-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2015-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]},
      {key: "2013-05", values: [{1:2}, {3:4}]}
    ]
  }
];

var a = _.map(data, (d) => {
  d.values = _.filter(d.values, (v) => {
    return Date.parse(v.key) > Date.parse("2014");
  });
  return d;
});
```